# How to restore x11 after removing xquartz on osx

Tags: macos, osx-snow-leopard, xorg

I tried to install xquartz but gave up half way, so i'm trying to remove it and go back to X11. I followed all the instructions here: http://xquartz.macosforge.org/trac/wiki/X11-UsersFAQ
But i think its not properly done, because when i try to start wireshark (which uses X), i get the following error:

```
(wireshark-bin:846): Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display:
```

Can someone help explain how i can ensure X11 is all set up right?

Comment: I think its something to do with my DISPLAY environment var. When i do 'set' from the terminal, there's no DISPLAY var set. Does that matter?

Comment: Heres something interesting in the output from when i try 'startx' from terminal: X11.app: No launchd socket handed off, unsetting DISPLAY

Comment: It's time you accept your own answer. This topic was just bumped to the front page by Community.

Answer (score 1):

Found a solution:

http://lists.apple.com/archives/x11-users/2010/Aug/msg00012.html

The bit i needed was the following:

```
launchctl load -w /System/Library/LaunchAgents/org.x.startx.plist
logout
login
```